Overlap one component on another and fill the height
I want one component to overlap another 32.dp and the overlapping component to fill the entire available height.
I tried to make that effect using offset modifier, but the problem i have is that the overlapping component doesn't fill the height.
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(0.3f).background(Color.Red))
    Box(
        Modifier.offset(y = (-32).dp).fillMaxSize()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 32.dp, topEnd = 32.dp))
            .background(Color.Green)
        )
}

This is the result i have obtained from the code above. I want the green box take all the height and there is no white.
Comparation between the result obtained and the desired one



Do you have image of desired outcome?

@Thracian i have edited the post with the desired result

You can use enableEdgeToEdge to draw below system bars. Since you call offset -32.dp you can use Modifier.layout to increase height of Green Box 32.dp bigger than parent. But since you don't abide parent Constraints, it will center green one. And for that you can add another y down 16.dp
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                CoverScreenLayout()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CoverScreenLayout() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.3f)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset(y = (-32).dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .layout { measurable, constraints ->

                    val wrappedConstraints = Constraints.fixed(
                        width = constraints.maxWidth,
                        height = constraints.maxHeight + 32.dp.roundToPx()
                    )

                    val placeable = measurable.measure(wrappedConstraints)
                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        placeable.placeRelative(0, 16.dp.roundToPx())
                    }
                }
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 32.dp, topEnd = 32.dp))
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}


Thanks for the response! It works! I was already using enableEdgeToEdge, so i have just had to use the layout modifier

You are welcome. By the way fillMaxSize modifier is useless, you can remove it. Also instead of using Modifier.offset, you can achieve same thing with placeable.placeRelative(0, -16.dp.roundToPx())

you can also build a custom layout if you want percentage based overlapping which gives you more contraol than using -negative values
